# Parse Data Model for users tagging items

Tags: swift, mongodb, parse-platform

im trying to figure out a good data model approach when using parse (underlying mongodb) for users that are allowed to select a tag and provide a value to them, lets call it just a rating since thats the easiest to understand.

Im working on a class that is called user tags that has the following structure currently in its collection.

- User (pointer to user class)
- Object (pointer to object to tag)
- Tags (array of tags with values)

The tags can be up to maybe 30 tags and each one of them can have a rating of 1-5 in this case...

I was wondering if I could do a PFRelationship in an array that has the objectId of the tag as the key and value as the 1 - 5 rating.. here is an example json object mocked up to what im saying.

```
{
  "3q24afadfadf": 3.5  //parse relation object id : value,
  "234rrdfadfk": 2.4 //parse relation object id : value,
  "as4q2w34lsdf": 2.3 //parse relation object id : value
}
```

This way I can store one row for the item that the user tagged and all the tags with its rating value along with that.

I'm not sure this is the right way or if its scalable when doing queries for get me all users items he or she tagged, along with the tag (name) and the values).

I also on top of that need to figure out a way to when many users tag the same item with different values that I build up some analytics or maybe counter class that gets incremented or averaged in to then be displayed along with the item.  I might try cloudcode to do saveafter to update the analytic data class for that item.

Anyhow Any thoughts on this model would be appreciated and most importantly need to be able to get at the data inside the tag array, with hopefully the key being a pointer, if not a pointer i'm up to suggestions because the result should return

- Item A
- Tag name 1 with value 4.5
- Tag Name 2 with value 3.5
  and so on..
  ...

Also if you have any pointers to how to build aggregated data of the item and its over all value that many users have tagged over time.. My thought as above is to have a analytic class that the cloud code increments or that the app then increments, the challenge is to load all the user tags of item x, and get the tag and value out of the array and then add them to the analytic class.  I could run this at night since it doesn't have to be real time.

Comment: Relationships are something you can query, not a dictionary with pointers as keys. Why wouldn't you have a tag class with the name and value and then either a pointer to the user or a relationship from the user?

Comment: An Item can have many tags associated with it and values for those tags. Since I do not know how many tags and values of those tags users will enter for Item A in this example, I thought of putting that into an array, of course then you cant have key value from what I understand but an array of pointers to tags.. the tricky thing is figuring out where to store those vaues.  I prefer to do this in one row instead of lets say 5 rows each with the tag (pointer), value , and item pointer.. I could see potentially millions of records if I go this route.  Suggestions?

Comment: One way to look at this would be lets call it a recipe app, where the user can enter the ingredients and time values.. I would prefer to have one document for all of this but ingredients can also lets say reference a list of items that your allowed to use from another class.  Sorry just trying to wrap my head around pointers but pointers that also have values attached to them with out creating one row per tag or ingredient with a time value attached to it. Just trying to wrap my head around what is more scalable as more people tag

Comment: I would have one row per tag and then another row of a different class for each row of that class. If you're going to have too many for parse I'd look at using a different back end.

Comment: Hmm in not sure if we are on the same page, can you give me an example of what you mean.. in a post below?